# C#, Nunit, Moq How to test that a presenter is subscribed to it's view events?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, mvp

I have a view who is a winform:

```
public partial class View : Form, IView
{
    private static object eventsLock = new Object();
    private EventHandler CustomClick;

    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.button.Click += FireCustomClickEvent;
    }

    event EventHandler IView.Click
    {
        add { lock (eventsLock) { this.CustomClick += value; }}
        remove { lock (eventsLock) { this.CustomClick -= value; }}
    }

    private void FireCustomClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CustomClick?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    public void MakeViewDoStuff()
    {
        //Do stuff...
    }
}
```

The `IView` interface is as follow:

```
public interface IView
{
    event Eventhandler Click;
    void MakeViewDoStuff();
}
```

And I have this presenter:

```
public class Presenter : IPresenter
{
    private IView view;
    public Presenter(IView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.AttachView();
    }

    private void AttachView()
    {
        this.view.Click += SomePresenterStuff;
    }

    private void SomePresenterStuff(object sender EventArgs e)
    {
        this.view.MakeViewDoStuff();
        //Do stuff now that the event was raised.
    }
}
```

Now I can test that the event is raised and that the presenter makes the view do stuff with this test function:

```
this.mockedView.Raise(v => v.Click += null, new System.EventArgs());
this.mockedView.Verify(v => v.MakeViewDoStuff(), Times.Once());
```

But what I want to know is: Should I test that the presenter is attaching in its constructor?

So basically, should I test that `private void AttachView()` is called in the constructor of Presenter and how would I do this?

Some notes:

I think that adding a Boolean flag to keep the attached state of the presenter is kind of a bad hack since it would involve changing the production code only to be able to test it and would not be used in production.

**EDIT:**

I kind of agree with Sergey Berezovskiy that it might not be the presenter responsability nor a behavior, but what if my view had a CloseView event, that when raised, the presenter should unsubscribe to the view events. Wouldn't we want to test this?

Comment: You would want to check this in the mocked view, but [Moq still can't verify event registration](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/49)

Comment: @stuartd Thanks this link was very usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe presenter's responsibility is

> *reacting* to view's Click event by doing some stuff

If that happens - who cares how presenter was attached to event? That's just technical details not related to business logic. Your current test verifies exactly what should be verified.

There are lot of technical stuff which you can verify

- presenter stores view in private field?
- presenter attaches to event?
- presenter stays attached over time?

But it doesn't really matter while presenter reacts to view's event in required way.

Comment: Well lets say I have this scenario: My view has a close event and the presenter should dettach from the view when its raised. Wouldn't this be a valid case where one would want to test events registration? Or should I just dettach the view in the presenter's destructor?

Comment: @Sebastien yes, I believe that's a valid business requirement - presenter should react to Close event so that any further events should have no reactions